# Toggle button with Popover menu : toggle button remains active when menu item is selected from popover item, I found crude solution, please refine

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, pygtk, popover, pygobject

I'm learning PyGobject (pygtk3), the example given at [pygtk popover tutorial](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/popover.html) includes some XML file for menu items. I don't want to use xml or glade .ui in my pygtk program. Hence created menu with 3 menu items. This example works very well, but it looks more like s hack. The toggle button which hosts the popover needs manual button activation/deactivation, as can be seen in the functions/methods in this example. Is there a better way to have button toggle and menu/hide show with toggle like this? I got some ideas watching [Michael B. Popover Tutorial - Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbySnfQimCs) We really need more pygtk/pygobject tutorials with practical examples for more people to join free software.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk


class PopoverWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Popover Demo")
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.set_default_size(300, 200)

        outerbox = Gtk.Box(spacing=6, orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        self.add(outerbox)

        #Menu button which will have popover
        self.menuButton = Gtk.ToggleButton.new_with_label("Click Me")
        self.menuButton.connect("toggled", self.on_click_me_clicked)
        outerbox.pack_start(self.menuButton, False, True, 0)

        self.popover = Gtk.Popover()
        vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        
        #popover menu adding items with buttons in vbox container
        vbox = Gtk.Box(spacing=1, orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        vbox.set_border_width(5)
        menu_item_button1=Gtk.ModelButton()
        menu_item_button1.set_label("Menu Item 1")
        menu_item_button1.connect("clicked", self.start_menu_item1_function)
        vbox.pack_start(menu_item_button1, True, True, 5)

        menu_item_button2=Gtk.ModelButton()
        menu_item_button2.set_label("Menu Item 2")
        menu_item_button2.connect("clicked", self.start_menu_item2_function)
        vbox.pack_start(menu_item_button2, True, True, 5)
        
        #add quit menu item
        menu_item_button3=Gtk.ModelButton()
        menu_item_button3.set_label("Quit")
        menu_item_button3.connect("clicked", Gtk.main_quit)
        vbox.pack_start(menu_item_button3, True, True, 5)
        
        #put the buttons in popover menu using vbox container
        self.popover.add(vbox)
        self.popover.set_position(Gtk.PositionType.BOTTOM)
                
    def start_menu_item1_function(self,button):
        #on selection of the menu in the popover
        #we need to manually toggle the button
        self.menuButton.set_active(False)
        print("1st menu item selected")
        
    def start_menu_item2_function(self,button):
        #on selection of the menu in the popover
        #we need to manually toggle the button
        self.menuButton.set_active(False)
        print("2nd menu item selected")

    # to make toggle button hide the show/hide the menu   
    def on_click_me_clicked(self, button):
        if  button.get_active():
            self.popover.set_modal(False)
            self.popover.set_relative_to(button)
            self.popover.show_all()
            self.popover.popup()
        else:
            self.popover.popdown()


win = PopoverWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

the [Menu Popover](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/popover.html#menu-popover) uses XML file, but I wanted no XML but manual menu items. Found a solution, but gtk.Window has to be put in Gtk.ApplicationWindow

[image] [image]

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import gi

# Popover menubutton without MENU XML
# manual Menu Items without XML using menu model
# Needs Application Window for Gtk.MenuButton + menuModel 

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio


class PopoverWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Popover Demo")
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.set_default_size(300, 200)

        outerbox = Gtk.Box(spacing=6, orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)

        #Menu button which will have popover
        self.menuButton = Gtk.MenuButton()
        self.menuButton.set_label("Click Me!")
        
        # Put the button in the container box
        outerbox.pack_start(self.menuButton, False, True, 0)
        self.add(outerbox)

        # Creating menu items Using Menu model
        menuModel = Gio.Menu()
        # menmodel items have (label) and action name with win.XX or app.XX
        menuModel.append("Item 1 - label 1", "win.XX")
        menuModel.append("About Your Computer", "win.About_Your_Computer")
        menuModel.append("Asif Ali Rizvan", "win.riz")
        
        # menu is set as the menu of the menubutton
        self.menuButton.set_menu_model(menuModel)

        
        # the set action XX from win.XX, skip the win. prefix
        
        #1st menu item
        about_action = Gio.SimpleAction.new("XX", None)
        about_action.connect("activate", self.item1_XX_method)
        self.add_action(about_action)

        # 2nd menu item
        about_action = Gio.SimpleAction.new("About_Your_Computer", None)
        about_action.connect("activate", self.about_your_computer_function)
        self.add_action(about_action)
        
        # 3rd menu item
        riz_action = Gio.SimpleAction.new("riz", None)
        riz_action.connect("activate", self.riz_callback)
        self.add_action(riz_action)

               
    def item1_XX_method(self, action, parameter):
        print("Menu Item 1 Selected")
        
    def about_your_computer_function(self, action, parameter):
        print("Your Computer is an Electronic Device.")

    def riz_callback(self, action, parameter):
        print("You clicked \"Asif Ali Rizvan\"")

win = PopoverWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's use of Popover with Menumodel, line 35, 36 commented and 2 lines of popover code added

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import gi

# Popover menubutton without MENU XML
# manual Menu Items without XML using menu model
# Needs Application Window for Gtk.MenuButton + menuModel 

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio


class PopoverWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Popover Demo")
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.set_default_size(300, 200)

        outerbox = Gtk.Box(spacing=6, orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)

        #Menu button which will have popover
        self.menuButton = Gtk.MenuButton()
        self.menuButton.set_label("Click Me!")
        
        # Put the button in the container box
        outerbox.pack_start(self.menuButton, False, True, 0)
        self.add(outerbox)

        # Creating menu items Using Menu model
        menuModel = Gio.Menu()
        # menmodel items have (label) and action name with win.XX or app.XX
        menuModel.append("Item 1 - label 1", "win.XX")
        menuModel.append("About Your Computer", "win.About_Your_Computer")
        menuModel.append("Asif Ali Rizvan", "win.riz")
        
        # menu is set as the menu of the menubutton
        #self.menuButton.set_menu_model(menuModel)

        # USE POPOVER instead
        popover = Gtk.Popover.new_from_model(self.menuButton, menuModel)
        self.menuButton.set_popover(popover)
        
        # the set action XX from win.XX, skip the win. prefix
        
        #1st menu item
        about_action = Gio.SimpleAction.new("XX", None)
        about_action.connect("activate", self.item1_XX_method)
        self.add_action(about_action)

        # 2nd menu item
        about_action = Gio.SimpleAction.new("About_Your_Computer", None)
        about_action.connect("activate", self.about_your_computer_function)
        self.add_action(about_action)
        
        # 3rd menu item
        riz_action = Gio.SimpleAction.new("riz", None)
        riz_action.connect("activate", self.riz_callback)
        self.add_action(riz_action)

               
    def item1_XX_method(self, action, parameter):
        print("Menu Item 1 Selected")
        
    def about_your_computer_function(self, action, parameter):
        print("Your Computer is an Electronic Device.")

    def riz_callback(self, action, parameter):
        print("You clicked \"Asif Ali Rizvan\"")

win = PopoverWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally Got better Popover + MenuButton + manual menu items by using ModelButton for nomal menu items, and widgets inside box containers. The MenuModel is not rich like popover with container with widgets as can be seen here:
[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import gi

# Popover menu button without MENU XML
# popover menu with different widgets
# using vbox container inside popover
# GPL3+ (C) Asif Ali Rizvan <fast.rizwaan@gmail.com>

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio
class PopoverWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Popover Demo")
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.set_default_size(400, 300)

        # box0 is the main box container which will hold the mb0
        box0 = Gtk.Box(spacing=6, orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        self.add(box0)

        # mb0 is Gtk.MenuButton which will include the coming popover
        mb0 = Gtk.MenuButton()
        mb0.set_label("Click Me")
        box0.pack_start(mb0, False, True, 0)

        # Create popover
        popover = Gtk.Popover()
               
        # vbox container for adding items in Popover menu
        vbox = Gtk.Box(spacing=1, orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        vbox.set_border_width(5)
        
        # 1st Gtk Entry widget
        menu_item_1= Gtk.Entry()
        #menu_item_1.set_text("Hello World")
        vbox.pack_start(menu_item_1, True, True, 5)
        
        # 2nd Gtk Toggle Button Widget
        menu_item_2= Gtk.ToggleButton()
        menu_item_2.set_label("Toggle Button")
        menu_item_2.connect("toggled", self.call_menu_item2_function)
        vbox.pack_start(menu_item_2, True, True, 5)

        # hbox is horzitontal box container for adding items sidewise 
        # in vbox of Popover menu.
        # we are packing container with widgets inside container (hbox in vbox)
        hbox = Gtk.Box(spacing=1, orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox.set_border_width(0)
                
        # 3rd Gtk Button
        menu_item_3=Gtk.Button()
        menu_item_3.set_label("Menu Item 3")
        menu_item_3.connect("clicked", self.call_menu_item3_function)
        hbox.pack_start(menu_item_3, True, True, 5)
        
        # 4th Add quit menu item
        menu_item_4=Gtk.CheckButton()
        menu_item_4.set_label("Quit")
        menu_item_4.connect("clicked", Gtk.main_quit)
        hbox.pack_start(menu_item_4, True, True, 5)
        
        # add hbox (horizontal box) in vbox (vertical box container of popover) 
        vbox.pack_start(hbox, True, True, 0)
        
        # add the vbox container with hbox+widgets and other widgets
        # in popover menu
        popover.add(vbox)
        popover.set_position(Gtk.PositionType.BOTTOM)
        
        # add the popover inside mb0 Gtk.MenuButton()
        mb0.set_popover(popover)

        # show the widgets
        popover.show_all()
        
    def call_menu_item2_function(self,button):
        print("Menu Item 2 button Toggled")

    def call_menu_item3_function(self,button):
        print("Menu item 3 Button Clicked")
        

win = PopoverWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```